# Convert between a C double and Cocoa's NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm converting an algorithm I wrote in Java to Objective-C.  In java the BigDecimal class handles base-10 numbers and can take the primitive double as a constructor arg.  In Cocoa's NSDecimalNumber class, however, there is no direct way to construct an instance using a primitive double.

Currently I'm using this (smelly) hack:

```
    [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.38f", number]];
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NSNumber, the superclass of NSDecimalNumber, has a +numberWithDouble: method. That's what you want.

Comment: NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble is the same method as NSNumber numberWithDouble. It will return NSNumbers and not NSDecimalNumbers (see my other comments about this).

Comment: @Danny Tuppeny: I just tested this and you appear to be wrong. I did `[[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:12.7] class]` and got back NSDecimalNumber. The error you refer to in your other comment is a static typing error in Cocoa AFAICT. The dynamic type is fine and works normally. The fact that `numberWithDouble:` only exists on NSNumber is irrelevant, since it just calls `[[[self alloc] initWithDouble:double] autorelease]`, and `self` is whichever class received the message. This is basic inheritance — classes can inherit their parents' convenience constructors.

Comment: Incidentally, for anyone interested, there was some discussion on the Cocoa-Dev mailing list a while back about the issue that Danny brings up. Basically, this is just different engineers using different styles in their headers and not foreseeing the consequences. The static-typing style of NSNumber's convenience constructors gives a little more static type protection (obviously) but leads to spurious errors like this when used with a subclass, so most classes return `id` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'd spent ages trying to figure out what was happening earlier (I'm relatively new to objective-c, coming from C#). Something to watch out for in future!

Comment: Doing this might suddenly not work anymore. Since the return type is still fixed at (NSNumber *) and not id or instancetype it might be that with an upgrade of iOS it no longer works causing your app to crash.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:(double)]`, it's just not as obvious.

Answer (score 3):

```
[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the way to get this to work, and to dismiss the warning is like this.

```
    NSNumber *temp = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:self.hourlyRate];
    myDecimal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[temp decimalValue]];
```

It gets rid of the warning, albeit being two lines instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

In other posts I'm finding info that using the `NSNumber` methods with `NSDecimalNumber` either will return `NSNumber`, or will return `NSDecimalNumber` but that's not what the spec says it should so it may be considered a bug and change in the future. Er something like that.